# How to check if an element contains a class in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Each paragraph in the DIVs with class "change" should have their font colour be red when the mouse is on them, and change back to black when the mouse is off. heres what I have:

```
var para = document.getElementsByTagName('p');

var c = document.getElementsByClassName('change');

for(let i = 0; i < para.length; i++) {

    para[i].onmouseover = function () {
      para[i].style.color = "red";
    }

    para[i].onmouseout = function () {
      para[i].style.color = "black";
    }
}
```

I've tried numerous things and feel like im missing something simple. html div class name is "change".

Comment: Can you give an example of the HTML?

Comment: `para[i].classList.contains(className)` - Read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)

Comment: how would this look in my code, ive tried this and had no luck

Comment: Note that your code only changes the style of the last `p` element as when the handlers are executed `i` equals to the index of last element in the set. Also your code doesn't use the `c` variable at all. What exactly do you want to do with that collection?

Comment: im trying to use the classList.contains method but im having trouble. how should the code look using this method?

Comment: What do you mean by "that are apart of the class 'change' " ?. You mean you want to change the colors of all paragraphs except the one with this class?

Comment: there are 3 divs and 2 have class change and 3 P tags in each div. only the divs with class change should have the p tags go red on mouse over.

Comment: you're right It is confusing now that i read it again. sorry in advance let me try to clear it up.  Each paragraph in the DIVs with class "change" should have their font colour be red when the mouse is on them, and change back to black when the mouse is off.

Comment: Please update your question instead of posting that in the comment section. You you can update your question limitlessly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, I have updated it to your needs.

```
let change = document.getElementsByClassName('change');
for(item of change){ 
  let para =item.querySelectorAll("p");
  for(let i = 0; i < para.length; i++) {

    para[i].onmouseover = function () {
      para[i].style.color = "red";
    }

    para[i].onmouseout = function () {
      para[i].style.color = "black";
    }
}
```

}

for more details check it out [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_queryselectorall.asp)

Comment: needs to check for class name not Id :/

Comment: Hey I have updated my answer, please check if it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you're looking for.

```
// Executed when page is loaded
window.addEventListener("load", siteLoaded, false);

function siteLoaded() 
{
    // Selects all p-elements
   let pTags = document.querySelectorAll("p");

   for(let i = 0; i<pTags.length; i++) {

    // Adds eventlistener to each <p> to handle mouseover
    pTags[i].addEventListener('mouseover', function(e) {
        e.target.style.color = 'red';
    }, false);

    // Adds eventlistener to each <p> to handle mouseout
    pTags[i].addEventListener('mouseout', function(e) {
        e.target.style.color = 'black';
    }, false);
   }
 }
```

If you want to target by classname and p-element use:

```
 let pTags = document.querySelectorAll("p.change");
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use hover in your css?

```css
.change:hover {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<p class="change">Will change red on hover</p>
<p>Wont change red on hover</p>
```

Comment: Why? That is what CSS is for.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply check it using this in javascript

```
element.classList.contains(class);
```